# Normally Closed Emergency Power Off UPS Wiring

Tags: cabling

We currently have a bunch of Tripp Lite UPS that we’re preparing to deploy emergency power off capabilities to throughout our network. I have been provided Normally Closed tail circuits to connect to our UPS equipment.

This is the diagram displaying the wire order from the voltage source.

[image: EPO Diagram]

*Courtesy of [Tripp Lite](http://www.tripplite.com/shared/techdoc/Owners-Manual/932486.pdf)*

This is what the connection should look like with all of the components involved.

```
------+                                          +------
      |   5                                      |
      |-----------------_                        |
      |   4              >-----------------------|
      |-----------------¯                        |
      |   3                                      |
      |-----------------===----------------------|
      |   2                                      |
      |-------X                                  +------
      |   1                                        EPO
      |-------X                                   SOURCE
      |
      |
------+
 RJ-11
 PLUG
```

I’ve been trying to come up with an graceful way of connecting these points.
How do I make this a reliable connection and look professional?
What have others done?

Comment: we need more info about your environment to make suggestions.  What does your EPO source look like?

Comment: The wires we have dropped off in our rack are in a standard CAT 5 cable and only a single pair is used.

Comment: When you say "dropped off," are they terminated?  Just hanging?   Is the cable long enough to reach the UPS? Can you add a 66 or 110 block in the rack?

Comment: "Dropped Off" means it's a cable hangining in the rack, waiting for my shop to do something with it.  It's certainly long enough to reach the UPS.  I can add anything I want, although, I'm certainly not going to add a 66 block to each rack for 3 wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be tempted to make an RJ-11 pig tail, and then solder or twist the wires to the EPO cable.  Heat shrink tubing over the whole thing to make it look "professional."

Comment: That was my original assumption. Is that the industry standard? We don't normally deal with wiring like this; all we have is ethernet and fiber, so this is a little off.